# How to refine my data from peaks

Tags: forecasting

For example I have data with small linear growth during the year, but with a lot of peaks that can be twice as an average in this month.

How to refine data from these peaks?

i dont want just to get a trendline, but I want to get a line of data how it looks without these peaks.

I can invent some stuff, but are there existing solutions?

edit

It is not like smoothing.

I want to make a trendline but without taking peaks.

Let's say I have 30 days sales data.
In 5 of them I had some peaks. But I want to get a graph more or less linear.

The solution should determine such peaks and put moving average values instead of peaky days, but with some trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your signal is very 'spiky', you can remove the peaks by applying a median filter. [Here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/remove-spikes-from-a-signal.html) is an example from the MATLAB documentation which should give you an idea how it works.

There are also other types of filters for signal smoothing such as using a moving average or the slightly more sophisticated Hampel filter. Again the MATLAB documentation has some very [good examples](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/signal-smoothing.html).

Comment: If the data are very spiky, using a median filter would reduce the area under the curve because the medians will be lower than the average. This could be problematic depending on the purpose of the analysis. Moving average could be better in that case.

Comment: @paveltr okay I'm glad to hear that. Would you mind accepting the answer in that case?